# System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1 instead of database table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have database CarsDB, with Table Car in it. I whant to see the car table, but getting only System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1 instead of database table

```
public CarsBDEntities db = new CarsBDEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Carlist = db.Cars.ToString();
        return View();
    }
```

I have make a table, then created a model from it. Using entity frameworkd and ado.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `ToString`; if you just return `db.Cars` instead, that will give you an `IEnumerable` that you can work with.

```
var cars = db.Cars;
return View(cars);
```

You can use this to make a Webgrid that will display your data.  Razor view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Models.Cars>

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert an ObjectSet to a string, which is why your getting "System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet". You'll need to pull the data out of the table to view it. For instance, something like:

```
string firstCarMake = db.Cars.FirstOrDefault().Make.ToString();
```